# No Logs in django developemnet server

Tags: python, django, postman

i am trying to hit the django REST API using POSTMAN , i am able to save the data using django rest views, but when i am trying to save data using the POSTMAN the api is giving 500 , and also no logs are printed on console

it just print this

```
[09/Apr/2016 10:08:28]"POST /userprofile HTTP/1.1" 500 73961
```

the actual error is not clear why this happens, please help

Answer (score 0):

Change the value of `DEBUG` variable in `settings.py` to `True`.

It give you all the informations you need in your browser if an error occurs (and in the console as well).

Comment: Django won't give a 74kb response to a 500 error unless you've already got debugging enabled.